# Mac screen flashes when f13 pressed?

Tags: mac, keyboard, keybindings

I recently discovered that when I press f13 on my mac keyboard, the screen flashes white. It look exactly like when you take a screenshot except, it's not taking a screenshot. I have looked through all my keyboard shortcuts in settings, and can't find anything that is assigned to f13. I have tried to search online and I can't find anything on f13 assigned to anything on mac. I also have a hard time believing that this would be assigned to anything on mac by default because you have to have the extended keyboard to press f13.

```
NOTE: I am on a mac with yosemite.
```

**EDIT:** It also seems to occur when you press backspace in terminal when there is nothing left to delete

**EDIT 2:** I currently don't have the setting to flash on alert, so I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess would be …

System Prefs > Accessibility > Audio
You have "Flash the screen when an alert sound occurs" checked.

F13 has no default task - & any invalid key pressed whilst in Finder will generate an alert [doesn't really do it in other apps, but does in Finder]

Comment: I currently don't have the setting to flash on alert, so I don't know what it is.

Comment: Press the 'test screen flash' button - does it look the same? It's a fade in/out so ought to be dissimilar to a graphics 'glitch' of any type [Also… does the Finder actually audibly 'beep' when you press it [with Finder frontmost]?